# How to get product collection with manufacturer attribute filter outside of Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I am newbie in Magento 2 I try to get product collection with attribute filter 'Manufacturer'.
I try to implement with below code but not get result-set as per manufacturer filter:-

```
$manufacturer = 'Bosch';
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->getManufacturerName($manufacturer,['eq'=> $manufacturer]);
$collection->setCurPage(9);
$collection->setPageSize(100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
$manufacturerLabel = 'Bosch';
$manufacturerValue = 10; //assumed value of manufacturer Bosch
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', $manufacturerValue); // here filter with manufacturer value instead of label 
$collection->setCurPage(9);
$collection->setPageSize(100);
```

Comment: Piyush I want to display manufacturer in collection array

Comment: Like [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 7159
            [attribute_set_id] => 16
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => CO2GSM3D
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2016-12-06 10:06:09
            [updated_at] => 2016-12-07 04:31:28
        ) here in this array I want manufacturer with manufacturer 'Bosch'

Comment: if manufacturer value is not displaying in collection array then make sure that you have assigned manufacturer attribute to the attribute set.

Comment: It is in default attribute set

Comment: Is the manufacturer attribute marked 'Use in product listing'? If not, try to set that flag to yes and reindex everything

Comment: Yes did..still no result

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: Piyush manufacturerValue is same as attribute_id? I am confused? How can I get manufacturerValue outside magento2.

Comment: manufacturer value is value of the attribute's option, you can check in edit product page by inspect element the manufacturer dropdown.

Comment: Manufacturer value I have find but result set not showing manufacturer in array.

Comment: remove Curpage and Pagesize from code and the try to loop then collection in `foreach`  the check for each product

Comment: Actually I want  who we register as a wholesaler  we would like them to have a Bosch discount of 24% discount off the web price but this is only for Bosch products. and 'BOsch is manufacturer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61683/discussion-between-piyush-suthar-and-ashwini).